# Identify "Forms" folder in a Sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm working on an application that shows a listing of files and folders within a Sharepoint document library. The file/folder list is created based on the SPList's `RootFolder.SubFolders` and `.Files` collections.

Is there a way to filter out the "Forms" folder from the results, **without hard-coding a check for a folder called forms**?

Comment: here you have a very good response with code: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52542/unable-to-seperate-normal-and-hidden-folder-such-as-forms-spfolder-object-mod

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check if the folder does not have an associated list item, i.e. if SPFolder.Item is null. Otherwise, hard-coding the name "Forms" should be ok as this does not change across different language versions of SharePoint.